# How do I combine two blocks of similar JavaScript Code?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way of writing some sort of function so that I don't have to keep rewriting the same type of code.

As you can see below, both blocks of code are pretty much the same except one is for the `lunchTimeSelector` and the other is for the `napTimeSelector`? Is there any way to write a function so that I can just automate this by just inputting an array like `[lunchTimeSelector, napTimeSelector, dinnerTimeSelector]`, etc. into a function to replace this code?

```
// Activates Lunch selector
var lunchTimeSelector =  document.getElementById("lunchTimeSelector");

var lunchEvent = function()
{
    lunchtime = lunchTimeSelector.value;
};

lunchTimeSelector.addEventListener("change", lunchEvent);





// Activates Nap-Time selector
var napTimeSelector =  document.getElementById("napTimeSelector");

var napEvent = function()
{
    naptime = napTimeSelector.value;
};

napTimeSelector.addEventListener("change", napEvent);
```

Comment: Think about a function where you will pass element id

Comment: Suggest you develop it a bit more with those two so we can better see what they are intended to do with their respective values. Then a more generic approach can be developed not just for setting separate event listeners but for whatever processing you do with those variables as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement it like so:

```
function addChangeEvent(id, handler){
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("change", handler);
}
[["lunchTimeSelector", function(){lunchtime = this.value}], 
 ["napTimeSelector", function(){naptime = this.value}]]
    .forEach(([id,handler])=>addChangeEvent(id,handler));
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try :

```
// wrap all your logic 
function lanuchNapTimeSelector(id,state){

 var target =  document.getElementById(id);

// your handelers
 var lunchEvent = function()
 {
    lunchtime = target.value;
 };

 var napEvent = function()
 {
    naptime = target.value;
 };

 target.addEventListener("change", state === "nap" ? napEvent : 
 lunchEvent);
}
```